# Static function is visible for another file

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how static functions work. I read that the static function can not be called from another file so I made a simple function in a file and than called it from another fail to see if it is callable. It is, but it shouldnt be.
Here is my first file: 
riko_driver which contains the function:

```
static void sfunc(void)
{
   puts("Static function has been called\n");
}
```

And this is my code (main.c) which calls the function from riko_driver.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <riko_driver.c>

int main(){
sfunc();
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}
```

As an output I got this: "Static function has been called"
But I shouldn't wright? Because I can not call static function from another file? I hope you understand my question. Excuse my bad English!

Comment: If you "include" `riko_driver.c` then it's *not* in another file (specifically it's in the same translation unit). Btw, why are you including .c files?

Comment: Forget about statics,first find out how to include user defined header file.

Comment: Don't use C but C++, which is a super C :D

Comment: @nbro : Some here say that C and C++ are actually two different languages ... And the problem above (inclusion of a source instead of a header) could be the same in C++. What about an anonymous namespace defined in one file included in another one ?

Answer (score 4):

You said:

> I read that the static function can not be called from another file

That is almost correct. It should be:

> A static function defined in one translation unit can not be called from another translation unit.

By adding

```
#include <riko_driver.c>
```

in `main.c`, you are making the contents of `riko_driver.c` part of the translation unit `main.c`.

If you want the `static` functions defined in `riko_driver.c` to be not usable from `main.c` but you want some `extern` funtions defined in `riko_driver.c` to be usable from `main.c`,

1. Create a header file, `riko_driver.h`, that contains the declarations of the `extern` functions.
2. Use `#include "riko_driver.h"` in `main.c` instead of `#include <riko_driver.c>`.
3. Use `#include "riko_driver.h"` in `riko_driver.c` so that the compiler checks consistency.
4. Compile `main.c` and `riko_driver.c` separately.
5. Link `main.o` and `riko_driver.o` to make the executable.

Comment: This actually does not answer the OP question, I think. He had thought that static functions were not callable from another file, but he discovered that god exists.

Comment: Thank you. So how to create a file that is not in the same compilation unit?

Comment: Note that the name used in the standard is Translation Unit.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §5.1.1.1 **Program structure** _A
source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing
directive `#include` is known as a_ preprocessing translation unit. _After preprocessing, a
preprocessing translation unit is called a_ translation unit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

To say that a static function can only be called in the file it has been defined is actually a shortcut to the fact that a static function only has visibility in the translation unit it has been defined. In C terminology we say that the identifier for the function has *internal linkage*.

If you include a file into another file and compile the source file you still have a single translation unit.